# Laravel : how create loop on key of arrayn with same name

Tags: arrays, laravel, loops

I have array recieved in blade templete like this :

```
{
  "absences1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "احمد",
      "stage": "سێ",
      "group": "A",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "احمد",
      "stage": "سێ",
      "group": "A",
    }
  ],
  "absences2": [
    
  ],
  "absences3": [
    
  ],
  "absences4": [
    
  ],
  "absences5": [
    
  ]
}
```

Now I want to loop on all absences to create same html for each data I tried this but dont work :

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= 5 ; $i++)
   $course=$absences.$i[0]->subj;
   $teacher=$absences.$i[0]->teacher;
@endif
```

How can I did this ?

Comment: I would like to get a cleaner description, try to describe the output expected :D, I would love to help

Comment: @kingbeencent thanks alot but i solved it muself and put the solution many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I solved it by using this :

```
@php
    $abs = "absences".$i;
    $course=$$abs[0]->subj;
    $teacher=$$abs[0]->teacher;
@endphp
```